# sudo not working on Kali running under WSL

Tags: sudo, kali-linux, password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed WSL 2 and used Kali (previously had version 1.0). In both versions I have an issue - I cannot use sudo. As soon as I execute it, I get:

```
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

As you we can all imagine, we cannot expect UNIX to work properly on Windows, but still...

So, where should I start from? Logs, checks?

Comment: Have you tried exiting the terminal and logging in again?

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with `sudo`, so I'm going to say this anyway. It requires the originator's password, not the target's password.

Comment: @roaima - that depends on what's specified in `/etc/sudoers` - specifically the `targetpw` option, amongst others.  The `sudo` default is originator password, so your advice is probably sound here, but worth noting that it may have been changed.

Comment: @TobySpeight agreed, but (IMO) highly unlikely given the OP didn't know where to start diagnosis.

Comment: @roaima, yes, unlikely in this circumstance, mentioned more for others arriving here.  And normally, sudo issues a prompt to indicate which user's password is required, so if that's present, then plain RTFS applies!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the `sudo` password should (at least in Kali) be the same as for your user.

In WSL, the default user and associated password are created the first time you run Kali after installation.  There is no root password.

Of course, in WSL, your user password isn't used much, since there's no "login".  Pretty much the only time you typically need it is for `sudo`.

But if you've forgotten it, it's fairly easy to recover in WSL.  From PowerShell or CMD (not from inside Kali), do the following:

```
wsl -u root passwd <username>
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you can run WSL under any username using the `-u` option.  No password is necessary, just as with most WSL operations, since WSL is limited to the permissions of your *Windows* user anyway.

If that still doesn't allow you to run `sudo`, then it's possible that your `sudoers` has an issue.  If all else fails, you can try removing the existing `/etc/sudoers` and then reinstalling it.

Before trying this, I recommend a full backup of the image, so I've included that as the first line here.  Again, this should be done from PowerShell or CMD:

```
wsl --export kali-linux snapshot.tar
wsl -u root rm /etc/sudoers
wsl -u root apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" sudo
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the c library libcrypt is missing, I had the same issue but with a straight Debian install, steps to resolve:

1. Login as root from cmd

```
wsl -u root
```

2. Resolve issue with libc6 not being configured, which is a dependency of libcrypt.

```
dpkg --configure libc6
```

3. Download libcrypt1 outside of apt, because apt is also broken:

```
wget http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.33-2_amd64.deb -O libcrypt1_4.4.33-2_amd64.deb
```

**OR** if you're experiencing this same issue on straight Debian, use their version of libcrypt1.

```
wget http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.18-4_amd64.deb -O libcrypt1_4.4.18-4_amd64.deb
```

6. Install the libc just downloaded

```
dpkg -i libcrypt1_4.4.*_amd64.deb
```

7. Check if you have other broken package dependencies, if you are you will see issues after attempting the apt upgrade.

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

8. Fix package dependencies (if required from last step failing), and run upgrade again which should now pass

```
apt --fix-broken install
apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, these commands helped me fix an upgrade from Debian 10 to Debian unstable/Sidney!

Answer (score -6):

In powershell, type

```
wsl --unregister <distro>
```

Then reinstall fresh.

Comment: Well, Welcome to Unix & Linux!  And, Ouch!  Sorry to see all the downvotes, but I do have to wonder why you would answer with essentially "reinstall" when I provided exact recovery steps in an earlier answer?!